# How to compare "block lists" for brokerages?

Tags: investing, brokerage, risk, online-brokerage, securities

I currently invest with Merrill Edge and they have a fairly strict *"block list"* and don't allow many high risk securities to be purchased. Here is an example: [Merrill Edge blocks active ETFs?! : investing](https://www.reddit.com/r/investing/comments/nkpmiv/merrill_edge_blocks_active_etfs/)

I am considering moving to a brokerage with a less strict *"block list"*. Is there anywhere on the web to compare block lists across brokerages such as TD Ameritrade, Robinhood, or Etrade? I'm not asking about a specific brokerage, but rather a recommended method to compare block lists.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are going to have to ask each brokerage what their criteria are and whether they would handle the transactions you have in mind -- remembering that they are free to change their policy at any time with only the obligation to close out transactions already in progress.

I'd also note that anything so risky that a major brokerage won't touch it is probably not something you should invest in unless you can afford to lose your entire stake. At least. Those restrictions are intended to protect their customers.